# Jquery para insert de seguidores

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde,

E o seguinte eu tenho uma área onde os utilizadores podem seguir outros utilizadores precisa de saber se com jquery ao clicar em seguir e possível inserir na tabela os dados e mudar o botão para não seguir e de outra cor se e possível e como posso fazer o jquery

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplor tabela users

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo

```
<script>
$(document.body).on('click', '#follow', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Evita o comportamento padrão
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/processa_seguidores.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataTtype: "JSON",
        data: {
            user_logged: <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>, //Aqui vai o usuário que clicou
            user_to_follow: <?php echo $row_foodies->id; ?>, //Aqui vai o id do usuário que gostaria de seguir
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data.error === 0) {
            $( this ).addClass( "unfollow" );
            $( this ).html( "Unfollow" );
            alert(data.message);
            //Uma sugestão você pode usar o Toastr (http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/)
            //para exibir seus retornos de forma mais elegante ao seu usuário
        } else {
            alert('Opa algum erro ocorreu');
        }
        console.log(data);
    });
})
</script>
<div class="my_account user wow fadeInLeft">
<figure>
    <a href="users/<?php echo $row_foodies->slug; ?>"><img style=" border-top-left-radius:10px; border-top-right-radius:10px;" src="<?php echo $row_foodies->user_foto; ?>" alt="" /></a>
</figure>
<div class="container_user" style="border-bottom-left-radius:10px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px;">
    <p><?php echo utf8_encode(limita_caracteres($row_foodies->fb_nome, 13, false)); ?></p>
    <div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-top:-15px; font-size:13px; color:#999;"><?php echo $bar['id']; ?> Opiniões</div> 
    <div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:0px 0px 10px 0px; font-size:13px; color:#999;">0 Seguidores</div> 
    <?php
    if($_SESSION['FBID'] || $_SESSION['user_id']){
    ?>
        <div id="#follow" class="seguir_user" style="margin:0px 0px 15px 0px; cursor: pointer;">Seguir</div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Tem mais informações, exemplos de sua tabela na base, de onde você tiraria a informação de identificação dos usuários.. ? Sim é possível só adiantando a pergunta.

Comment: tirava a informação da tabela users isso não e o problema não e como posso clicar no botão seguir e inserir os dados e mudar o botão para não seguir e mudar a cor sem actualizar a pagina

Comment: O que eu quis dizer é, de onde você vai pegar o id do usuário que ele quer seguir, onde ele está? Está disponível na página?

Comment: sim está disponivel na pagina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo bem simples para você e é preciso complementar claro para a sua necessidade, mas o básico acredito estar ai:

**Script**

```
  <script>
        $(document.body).on('click', '#follow', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //Evita o comportamento padrão
            $.ajax({
                url: "addfollower.html",
                type: "POST",
                dataTtype: "JSON",
                data: {
                    user_logged: Y, //Aqui vai o usuário que clicou
                    user_to_follow: X, //Aqui vai o id do usuário que gostaria de seguir
                }
            }).done(function(data) {
                if (data.error === 0) {
                    $( this ).addClass( "unfollow" );
                    $( this ).html( "Unfollow" );
                    alert(data.message);
                    //Uma sugestão você pode usar o Toastr (http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/)
                    //para exibir seus retornos de forma mais elegante ao seu usuário
                } else {
                    alert('Opa algum erro ocorreu');
                }
                console.log(data);
            });
        })
    </script>
```

**Página addfollower.php**

```
    <?php 
    $userOn = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user_logged', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $userToFollow = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user_to_follow', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //Garante que receberá um inteiro

    //Aqui vai seu sql;
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO FOLLOWER (id_user, id_follower) VALUES ($userOn, $usertoFollow)";
    //Aqui você trata o retorno como preferir;
    return json_encode(['error' => 0, "message" => "Você agora está seguinte: XY|"]);
```

**CSS**

```
.unfollow {
    background-color: #FF123F;
}
```

> Lembrando também que nada disso foi testado e pode conter algum erro
>   de sintaxe;

Comment: obrigado vou testar e digo algu

Comment: @CésarSousa Fiz algumas modificações interessantes agora... pode testar e modificar como precisa...

Comment: fiz aqui um teste mas ao clicar nao funciona

Comment: @CésarSousa Você mudou os identificadores de acordo com seu código? ali no #follow, você precisa trocar pelo id do seu botão na página, isso ali foi só um exemplo...

Comment: sim mudou conforme necessecito

Comment: Mas então o que não funciona mais exatamente? A página recebe o ajax?

Comment: Coloquei o codigo em cima

Comment: @CésarSousa no id="" <--- você não precisa colocar o #, somente coloque id="follow", só pro jquery, css... em fim o # diz para eles que é um id;

Comment: tem razão foi engano meu agora ja funciona porem retorna erro tenho de ver o que e

Comment: @CésarSousa para simplificar a sintaxe <?php echo $valor ?>, você pode utilizar <?= $valor ?>; vai ajudar bastante na legibilidade. Qualquer dúvida também estamos a disposição.

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode inserir dados no banco de dados por uma linguagem de cliente como Javascript (a não ser que esteja usando [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) e pelo que vi não é seu caso).

Você poderia criar uma página no seu website com a linguagem de servidor de sua preferência, no seu caso PHP, que receba requisições e nessas requisições vocẽ envia os dados que devem ser inseridos. Essa chamada assíncrona de cliente e servidor se chama [Ajax](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX_%28programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29).

Você pode tratar essas requisições do mesmo modo que trata as requisições de envio formulário normal com a variável [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php) ou [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php) do PHP.

O jQuery possui nativo uma funcionalidade que permite você fazer isso. [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

E sobre alterar as cores, não é dificil. Você pode usar as funções nativas do jQUery [CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/) ou a[ddClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Comment: não percebi muito bem como e a primeira vez que vou fazer um sistema de seguidores

Comment: Qual seria a melhor solução para fazer esse sistema visto que irá ter notificações

Comment: Se você procura o código pronto para você, você não encontrará aqui. Os conceitos necessários para você fazer o que quer eu citei acima. Basta entender de AJax e tudo ficará claro. Dá uma lida nos links.

Comment: Código feito eu nao gosto muito pois uma pessoa não aprende e eu sempre gosto de fazer de raiz

Comment: Então basta ler os links de Ajax que te mandei e ficará apto a fazer o seu sistema uma vez que esse conceito é super fácil. APenas enviar uma requisição para um servidor pelo cliente. Dei uma editada com mais links!

Comment: ok mas posso usar o NodeJS para esse efeito ?

Comment: Poderia mas o NodeJS ele trabalha tanto para cliente e servidor, substuindo o PHP nessa parte. Para fazer isso você deverá ter outros conhecimentos como Javascript e NodeJS em si. Acredito que AJax é a melhor solução e mais simples

Comment: ok vou optar por o ajax então mas tenho de estudar melhor isso pois já estou a ver que nao vai ser facil fazer o sistema de notificacoes

Comment: Vai ser excelente para seu crescimento pessoal como desenvolvedor. Os links acima tenho certeza que irão te ajudar. Bons estudos!

Comment: Ok obrigado pela ajuda